# Matlab get value from csv file

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file data I would use.
I would like from two input values from columns B and C ​​get the name from column A.
Example: from these two values

```
​​var1 = 12.90050072 
var2 = 55.95981118

I would get "ALIOTH"
```

here data

```
A             B        C
ALGOL   3.13614789  40.95564610
ALIOTH  12.90050072 55.95981118
ALKAID  13.79233003 49.31324779
```

I can load the csv file, but can not browse the data.

```
function [name] = getNameObject(ad,dec)
  fileID = fopen('bdd.csv');
  C = textscan(fileID, '%s %f %f','Delimiter',';');
  fclose(fileID);
```

Please suggest some functions and sample code to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will need to compare floating point values, direct numeric comparisons don't work a lot of the time. Here I will make use of string comparisons to achieve what you need:

```
clear;

fid = fopen('test.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s', 'Delimiter', ';');
fclose(fid);

val1 = input('Enter the first input: ', 's');
val2 = input('Enter the second input: ', 's');

if(find(ismember(C{2},val1)) == find(ismember(C{3},val2)))
    output = C{1}{find(ismember(C{2},val1))}
else
    disp('No match found!');
end
```

Now the result would be something like:

```
>> test
Enter the first input: 1.03
Enter the second input: 4.12
No match found!
>> test
Enter the first input: 12.90050072
Enter the second input: 55.95981118

output =

ALIOTH
```

Here I'm assuming, as per what I could deduce from your code, that the delimiter was a semi-colon. As such, my input data was:

```
A;B;C
ALGOL;3.13614789;40.95564610
ALIOTH;12.90050072;55.95981118
ALKAID;13.79233003;49.31324779
```

Comment: It would perfect if possible to get the same result with approximate value of val1 and val2. Example: val1= 13.001 and  val2 = 57.210  will give => "ALIOTH"

Comment: @user359706: That'd be more of the numeric nature. As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `importdata` and then check with tolerance. The reason being that floating point queries work well for inequalities, but not for equalities.

Answer (score 1):

I use `importdata` to deal with csv-s

aa.csv:

```
A,             B,        C
ALGOL,   3.13614789,  40.95564610
ALIOTH,  12.90050072, 55.95981118
ALKAID,  13.79233003, 49.31324779
```

importdata('aa.csv').data:

```
3.1361   40.9556
12.9005   55.9598
13.7923   49.3132
```

importdata('aa.csv').textdata:

```
'A'         '             B'    '        C'
'ALGOL'     ''                  ''         
'ALIOTH'    ''                  ''         
'ALKAID'    ''                  ''
```

Comment: Once you convert the data to floating point, comparisons won't always work perfectly.